# Is there a python version of Mitchell's face pose recognition code?

Tags: python, c

The original code for chapter 4 in Tom Mitchell's book for recognizing face pose from images is here:  http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/user/mitchell/ftp/faces.html

But it's in C, not that there is anything wrong with that and I guess that's a really good project to try to port it to Python but I am looking for something I can `git clone` quickly and use for a personal project.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a Notebook (ipynb) file with an implementation of this algorithm.  It is available on [Github](https://github.com/samantaheri71/Tom-Mitchell-s-Facial-Recognition-Python-Code)